# Not able to store Spark Dataframe to Cassandra using DataStax Spark Cassandra Connector

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, sbt, datastax

I am trying to write spark dataframe to a cassandra table using datastax spark cassandra connector. My scala version is : 2.11.8 and dependencies are as following :

```
libraryDependencies += "com.datastax.spark" % "spark-cassandra-connector_2.10" % "1.6.2"

libraryDependencies += "com.datastax.cassandra" % "dse-driver" % "1.1.2"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.0.1"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.0.1"
```

I am using following code to store the dataframe into the table :

```
finaldf.write.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").options(Map("table" -> "data","keyspace" -> "test")).save()
```

But I keep getting following error :

```
com.datastax.driver.core.DefaultResultSetFuture cannot be cast to shade.com.datastax.spark.connector.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: your cassandra connector to start isn't good. you are using the one compiled for scala 2.10

Comment: take a look at the compatibility matrix here https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector

Comment: I've tried using `libraryDependencies += "com.datastax.spark" %% "spark-cassandra-connector" % "2.0.0"` also. But the same errors occur immediately after executing the project.

Comment: I'm not sure what there is in the other datastax dependency but you ought also check that

Comment: you can try removing dse driver